# Ruby + Eclipse + "Dynamic Languages Toolkit for Ruby" plugin

Tags: ruby, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, require, dltk

I installed **Dynamic Languages Toolkit for Ruby** plugin in eclipse and it is not working:

**Details:**

- *Eclipse version:* Eclipse 4.2.2
- *OS Details:* Ubuntu 10.04
- *Ruby version:* ruby 1.9.2p180

THis is my ruby code:

```
# cat array.rb 
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "awesome_print"

hash = {
        :name => "your_self",
        :place => ["where", "somewhere"],
} 
ap hash
```

and here is the ERROR when this is run from eclipse:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- awesome_print (LoadError)
```

HOwever, I can run this code from console manually and it gives me the output:

```
# ruby array.rb 
{
     :name => "your_self",
    :place => [
        [0] "where",
        [1] "somewhere"
    ]
}
```

Needless to say, I do have `awesome_print` gem installed:

```
# gem list | grep awesome
awesome_print (1.2.0)
```

In Eclipse, I do have ruby interpreter set as below:
[image]

**QUESTION:** This issue is seen only when I use `require` in my code. Otherwise Eclipse can run the ruby code fine. What am I missing in my eclipse?

**UPDATE:**

If I use:

```
require "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/awesome_print-1.2.0/lib/awesome_print.rb"
```

then Eclipse is able to run the code fine. So I think this has something to do with ruby/eclipse `search path` of something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something weird is going on. Instead of `#!/usr/bin/ruby`, I had to make it `#!/usr/local/bin/ruby`.

I had to make similar changes in ruby interpreter setting in eclipse. Now my code is working fine.

So, Now I realized I actually have two versions of ruby installed:

```
# /usr/bin/ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [i686-linux]
# /usr/local/bin/ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [i686-linux]
```

I don't know how the version `2.0.0` got installed.

I had installed only `1.9.2`. and then ran `gem install awesome_print`

So, if I change the `shebang` and `eclipse` to use the ruby `2.0.0`, it is working fine. Probably, my `awesome_print` got installed only for 2.0.0

This is so confusing. Anyway. I am  good now. Ruby learning !!!

But then again, how come I was able to run the same program fine from command line even with ruby verion `1.9.2` ?

**UPDATE:**

So, I was wrong, When I ran `ruby array.rb` it was actually running `/usr/local/bin/ruby` and hence it worked from the command line. But in eclipse, I had set the ruby interpreter as `/usr/bin/ruby` which was `1.9.2.` and it was giving errors.

I could reproduce the same error from command line by running `/usr/bin/ruby array.rb`.

So...

This means, my installation of ruby 1.9.2 is not good. I still don't know where ruby `2.0.0` came from. But Now, I should uninstall and get rid of `1.9.2`.